# After system reboot can't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-2.2, debian

in order to be able to use a jquery plugin to upload files i had to increase some variables from php.ini, so i had to reboot, I used the webmin option to reboot system, now it seems that the connection to mysql fails

This is the error

> Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to
>   connect via unix:///var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock) in
>   /var/www/integracion/includes/basedatos.php on line 10 Warning:
>   mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/integracion/includes/basedatos.php on line 10 No such file or
>   directory

any clue would be very helpfull

Comment: So have you started mysql???

Comment: it looks like started in webmin procesess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ss` command to see whether `mysql` already run or not.

```
ss -anlp
```

If `mysql` is not running, use

```
mysqld_safe &
```

If it alse can't connect to `mysql` by doing this,
Check the /etc/my.cnf.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL server isn't running. Run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: 7953401631:~# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start                                                                                                                                     
-bash: sudo: command not found                                                                                                                                                 
7953401631:~#